# Do I need a separate image set for both iPhone 4 and iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, iphone-5

I have an app for iPhone 4 which includes over 1000 .jpg photo images. My question is:
Do I need a separate image set for iPhone 5?
I'm guessing the answer must be 'yes', since after extensive googling I can't find anything, but I would really like confirmation before embarking on a big task, resizing from the originals which will also involve cropping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.  The only case in which you would need iPhone 5 specific images to avoid stretching of images should be when you have UIImageViews which will have sizes that will change with the screen size such as a full-screen image.

Since a full-screen UIImageView will be 1136x640 instead of 960x480, you will need to create the image again for iPhone 5 since that size is directly tied to the screen size.  However, if you have any UIImageViews that have a standardized size (such as a 100x100 UIButton image), these images can be left as they are since the iPhone 5 will just need the same 200x200 retina image that the iPhone 4 would've loaded.

Comment: Thanks, So, if I want to take advantage of the increased screen size, I need new images. Otherwise, use the same images and accept unused space.

Comment: Yes, if your images were full-screen or screen-size dependent, those would be your two options.  Also, make sure to double-check your autoresizing masks.